# How do I solve ImportError: cannot import name 'Tweet' from 'GetOldTweets3.models.Tweet'

Tags: python, import, pip

I am trying to import GetOldTweet3 and make a query search but there is a problem with the import I guess, I tried to reinstall the package but nothing changed.

ImportError: cannot import name 'Tweet' from 'GetOldTweets3.models.Tweet' (C:\Users\2019\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\GetOldTweets3\models\Tweet.py)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aZYI.png)

Answer (score 1):

Next time it is better to post the codes as text, not as images.

By the way, `GetOldTweet3` has a class called `Tweet` [Documentation](https://pypi.org/project/GetOldTweets3/). And also you have created a `Tweet.py` file also. The problem is when you were trying to call the `Tweet class`, the program cannot decide which type of `Tweet` should be run (the file or the class).

**Solution -:** Rename your `Tweet.py` to another name which not belongs to any class type.

If above solution didn't work, please post the codes of main.py and Tweet.py as texts, not as images.